# Cakephp component startup for helper

Tags: cakephp

Is there some alternative that can be used in helper similar to startup in component. Actually I need to set some settings before helper method call, which is based on the called method. So, I need to detect which method is called and set what I need, which will be used in the helper method itself.

cake 2.x

**udpate**

helper's constructor is equivalent to component's initialize method, rather then startup, e.g. when I put this in my helper

```
public function __construct($View, $settings = array()) {
    parent::__construct($View);

    echo "test";die;
}
```

and include the helper in my helper's list, and open a page that does not contain any method call from that helper, after all I see the `test` echoed. But I need to echo that only when there is a method call, which is similar to component's startup, and not initialize.

Thanks

Comment: @burzum, nop, constructor is similar to initialize and not to startup, please see the updated question. thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Controller::startup()` doesn't work like what you are describing, `startup()` is invoked no matter if you are calling a method of the component, so the helpers constructor *is* similar to that.

Anyhow, if you need to do something before specific method calls, but don't want to implement it in the methods themselves, then implement your methods protected and use the magic `__call` handler to do whatever you need to do in beforehand and to invoke the actual methods.

Something like

```
public function __call($method, $params) {
    switch($method) {
        case 'foo':
            // do something special before _foo()
            break;

        case 'bar':
            // do something special before _bar()
            break;

        // ...

        default:
            parent::__call($method, $params);
            return;
    }

    return call_user_func_array(array($this, '_' . $method), $params);
}

protected function _foo($foo, $bar) {
    // ...
}

protected function _bar($bar, $foo) {
    // ...
}
```

See **http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php** for more information.